# jquery plugin for tag @name project members and #lables

Tags: jquery, tags, members

is there an jquery plugin that we can use for an input text to tag usernames

like this:
@name  that it gives autocompletion of the names
and also for #tag

[image]

Comment: I don't know it there are some jquery plugin that do what you need, but you can do yourself width simple autocomplete, take a look of this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/9R4cV/381/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this jquery plugin:

http://daniel-zahariev.github.io/jquery-textntags/

this should work